# Convert date format from 22/08/2015 20:36

Tags: php

Good afternoon!
I have a simple question.
I have a date format in PHP
$ originalDate = "22/08/2015 20:36";
How to translate
2015-08-20 00:00:00
?

Comment: Use `date` function.

Comment: I do not really understand how to do it

Comment: Then read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $originalDate = "22/08/2015 20:36";
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $originalDate);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```